# delegate methods stopped being called (used to work)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

i am setting up a delegate in a `RequestManeger` class like this :

```
@protocol Resend_Verify_Delegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)VerifyResponse:(NSString*)response;
-(void)Re_Failed;

@end


@interface RequestManeger : NSObject < ASIHTTPRequestDelegate > {
id <Resend_Verify_Delegate> Re_Delegate;   
}
```

i am synthesizing in the `RequestManeger.m` file as well.

after that i am importing the `RequestManeger.h` int my `ViewController.h` file and confirm to the protocol i have created. int the `ViewController.m` file i am calling a line to set the delegate like so : `[RequestManeger sharedManeger].Re_Delegate = self;` and applying the methods as well.
here is how i set the call from the `RequestManeger` class :

```
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.com];
NSLog(@"%@",url);

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [request.responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
    [self.Re_Delegate VerifyResponse:[dictionary valueForKey:@"Message"]];
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"%@", request.error);
    [self.Re_Delegate Re_Failed];
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

calling to the methods does happend, but it does not invoked in the `ViewController.m` file now.

i am kind'a frustrated about it,
any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done like this sample ??
In your .h of Say TempViewController class

```
@protocol TempViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) yourMethod
@end

@interface TempViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (assign) id<TempViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Synthesize this delegate in your .m file

call your delegate's method wherever you want using 
[self.delegate yourMethod]

Now , In another class where you want to implement this delegate try like this..

**#import "TempViewController.h"**

@interface SecondViewerVC : UIViewController 
{
}

### in your .m File

Init your object of TempViewController

```
objTempVC = [[TempViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TempViewController" bundle:nil];    
objTempVC.delegate = self;
```

---

And implement your method here

- (void) yourMethod { }

This will work for you definitely :)

Answer (score 1):

check if Re_Delegate is nil...

why did you write self.Re_Delegate? i think there must be 
   [Re_Delegate Re_Failed]
you have not property of the object